# Calculating the Character frequency in a String using C

Tags: c

I have written a program to calculate the character frequency in a string entered by the user. It's giving correct output for all lower case letters but it's not working for upper case letters. I am unable to find the problem in the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char string[100];
   int c = 0, count[26] = {0};

   printf("Enter a string\n");
   fgets(string,100,stdin);

   while(string[c] != '\n') {
      c++;
   }
   string[c] = '\0';
   c = 0;

   while (string[c] != '\0')
   {
      /** Considering characters from 'a' to 'z' only
          and ignoring others */

      if (string[c] >= 'a' && string[c] <= 'z') 
         count[string[c]-'a']++;
      else if(string[c] >= 'A' && string[c]<= 'Z')
         count[string[c]-'A']++;

      c++;
   }

   for (c = 0; c < 26; c++)
   {
      /** Printing only those characters 
          whose count is at least 1 */

      if (count[c] != 0)
         printf("%c occurs %d times in the entered string.\n",c+'a',count[c]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Please Help!

Here is the screenshot. Hopefully you will understand what problem I am facing:

[image]

It's not counting the upper case letters.

Comment: `while(string[c] != '\n')` is risky. What if the user entered more than 100 characters?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem -- it works fine for me.

Comment: Works fine here too.

Comment: What is the input text used? What was the incorrect output?

Comment: I guess: Do you want a separated frequency of lower and upper case chars?

Comment: I **do** understand that this kind of "homework" assignments plays it quick & dirty on what constitutes a "letter", but it still p{...}ses me off to no end. There are more than 26 letters existing. Better get into the habit of remembering that, and coding appropriately, right from the start. Those are bad habits, and they are hard to break once you aquired them. José wants to keep his four letters, `Straße` becomes `STRASSE` in uppercase, and if you're in Turkey, the uppercase `I` becomes `ı`, not `i`...

Comment: @DevSolar I sort of agree with you, but C doesn't play very well with Unicode. For a beginner it would be too much.

Comment: @JohnColeman: The problem being, beginners getting away with this over and over and over and over again. Every new generation of engineers blissfully unaware of all the problems that *proper* text handling involves. Not even as much as `<ctype.h>` in sight, let alone a hint at [ICU](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/). It just winds me up.

Comment: @DevSolar It is probably easier for a student who learns to program in C to later on learn a Unicode-friendly language like Python than it would be for a student who learns in something like Python to later on learn to understand the fine points of pointers and memory management. On the whole I still think that C is the best first language for anyone who wants to *really* learn programming, even at the cost of initially restricting the student to the ascii universe.

Comment: @JohnColeman: You misunderstood my meaning. I consider it negligent in the extreme for any C instructor, or C tutorial, or indeed answerer of a SO question, to not **immediately** point at such constructs and go "broken!!!". (Indeed, it doesn't take Unicode to break the OP's program, EBCDIC would be sufficient.) Instead, we've basically given up. It's not "Unicode-unfriendliness" of C that's killing the language, it's that we allowed it to get to the point where we no longer bother to point out such mistakes. "Ah well, it's C, it's a beginner, he'll be cushioned by Python..." -- bleh.

Comment: @DevSolar I've taught C programming on a couple of occasions and have *always* mentioned that C's native handling of strings is seriously deficient. Forget about issues of encoding, it is just silly to have to do a linear scan for `\0` to determine the length of a string. I suspect that most instructors point out some of these weaknesses. As far as needing to *immediately* point it out -- we all have our pet peeves. I tend to reserve my wrath for `gets()` :)

Comment: @JohnColeman If my input consists of upper case alphabets it does not count it. I want to ignore the case while counting. I mean 'a' and 'A' both should be considered as 'a' ignoring the case.

Comment: @BitanBasak I just saw your screenshot and am unable to replicate that behavior. Either the code you posted isn't the code you are running or (perhaps) there is something nonstandard about your terminal.

Comment: @BitanBasak There is **no** problem with the counting in the code presented. Will you please try and compile and run that code and see if you can reproduce. And if you can, give us more information. And also no need for screenshots, just paste the output into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine, but the output may be confusing you!

For the input string "Foo", the output is this:

```
f occurs 1 times in the entered string.
o occurs 2 times in the entered string.
```

Lower and uppercase are counted together, so you don't see "F occurs 1 times".

http://ideone.com/ACJnPD

Comment: Thanks! Your code showed me what I was doing wrong.

Comment: @BitanBasak May I ask what you found out was wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The only issue that I can see is bounds...

**EDIT**

This can be entirely skipped since `fgets()` ensures a trailing `'\0'` and you handle `'\n'` gracefully later in your checks.

```
while(string[c] != '\n') {
    c++;
}
string[c] = '\0';
```

To remove the `'\n'` it should be

```
while(string[c] && string[c] != '\n') {
   c++;
}
string[c] = '\0';
```

and

```
while (string[c] != '\0')
```

is good because of the semantics of `fgets()`.

Comment: `while (c < 100 && string[c] != '\0')` is not needed.  `string[c] != '\0'` is sufficient.  `string[]` will be null character terminated if `fgets()` does not return `NULL`

Comment: @chux I didn't know that about `fgets()`.

Comment: Corner case:  when `stdin` is closed, `fgets()` may return with the `string[]` having less than 100 characters read into it and still lack a `'\n'`.  In such a case the `string[c] = '\0';` is a problem.  Interestingly, there is no need for code to lop off the potential trailing `'\n'`.

Comment: @chux Edited for the corner case.

Answer (score 0):

IGuessing that the problem is to separate count of Upper and Lower case character you could use different arrays to count frequencies:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char string[100];
   int c = 0, countLower[26] = {0};
   int countUpper[26] = {0};

   printf("Enter a string\n");
   fgets(string,100,stdin);

   while((string[c] != '\0') && (string[c] != '\n')) {
      c++;
   }

   string[c] = '\0';
   c = 0;

   while (string[c] != '\0')
   {
      /** Considering characters from 'a' to 'z' only
          and ignoring others */

      if (string[c] >= 'a' && string[c] <= 'z')
          countLower[string[c]-'a']++;
      else if(string[c] >= 'A' && string[c]<= 'Z')
          countUpper[string[c]-'A']++;

      c++;
   }

   for (c = 0; c < 26; c++)
   {
      /** Printing only those characters
          whose count is at least 1 */

      if (countLower[c] != 0)
         printf("%c occurs %d times in the entered string.\n",c+'a',countLower[c]);
      if (countUpper[c] != 0)
         printf("%c occurs %d times in the entered string.\n",c+'A',countUpper[c]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```